Kafka consumerdoesn't receive messages in docker
I am creating a very basic consumer/producer setup for Kafka. I am using both Zookeper and Kafka with a Docker compose. Both seem to be connecting but when it comes to produce or consume, nothing happens. I can see the topic created and saw this in the kafka container log when it starts up. Not sure if it's related.
[2024-05-20 14:32:40,797] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1's connection to broker kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
2024-05-20 16:32:40 java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) failed.
2024-05-20 16:32:40     at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
2024-05-20 16:32:40     at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:298)
2024-05-20 16:32:40     at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:251)
2024-05-20 16:32:40     at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:131)

I am almost certain I am missing something in the docker compose file but I cannot figure out what, tried several options around the internet but couldn't solve it.
These are the files:
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
zookeeper:
  image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
  hostname: zookeeper
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - '2181:2181'
  environment:
    - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
kafka:
  image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
  hostname: kafka
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - '9092:9092'
  environment:
    - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
    - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    - KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    - KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=1
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost

Consumer.java
public class Consumer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
    String groupId = "my-fourth-application";

    // create consumer configs
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);

    try (final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties)) {
        consumer.subscribe(List.of("consumer_test"));
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

}

}
Producer.java
public class Producer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    config.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(config);
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("consumer_test", "consumer_key", (i++)+"");
        producer.send(record);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}

}

Are your producer/consumer running in containers too?  Internally Kafka advertises the locations of all of the connected brokers when you connect to it, and so the hostname differences inside vs. outside of Docker make a difference here.

@DavidMaze no, they are running in my local machine through IntelliJ.

Did you copy this compose file from somewhere? KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is a deprecated property and the bitnami kafka container no longer needs Zookeeper

I assume you are creating suck stack for development/learning reason.
I cannot reproduce your scenario here, but I can suggest you how to solve issues on local development environments which I experienced in the past.
So, try adding to each container the network_mode: host such follow:
version: '3'

services:
zookeeper:
  image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
  hostname: zookeeper
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - '2181:2181'
  environment:
    - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  network_mode: host
kafka:
  image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
  hostname: kafka
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - '9092:9092'
  environment:
    - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
    - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    - KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    - KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=1
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
  network_mode: host

Doing so your containers will share the host local network without any restriction.
Please tell me if it will work.

Yeah, I am doing this for learning reasons. I did what you asked and it didn't work.
